# android passing values to post method

Tags: android, post, parameters

Following is my code to hit a server for login process, using post method.

Here i need to pass 4 values which i am sending in json format

```
  public static LoginPageResponse checkLogin(Context context, String username, String password) throws Exception {

        String ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        String roleID = "1";
        String configParams = Utils.configWithNeededParams(new LoginPost(username, password, ID, roleID));

        Map<String,String> nameValuePairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
        nameValuePairs.put("",configParams);


        InputStream inputStream = HTTPHelper.executePostAsInputStream(context, getUrl(Constant.LOGIN_JSON), nameValuePairs);
        if (inputStream == null) {
            return null;
        }
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

        GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
        try {
            LoginPageResponse loginResponse = gson.create().fromJson(inputStreamReader, LoginPageResponse.class);
            return loginResponse;
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            throw new JsonSyntaxException("Issue parsing server Login data. Please try again later.", e);
        }
    }

    public static InputStream executePostAsInputStream(Context context, String pageUrl,  Map<String,String> nameValuePairs) throws IOException, IllegalAccessException {
        URL url = new URL(pageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(20000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.close();

        conn.connect();

        // read the response
        System.out.println("Response Code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
        //InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
        String response = in.toString();
        System.out.println(response);
        return in;
    }
```

The json format is added in Map nameValuePairs, i dont know how to add the parameters along with my url

Answer (score 0):

You can POST a [`JSONObject`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) directly to the server by setting the header parameters of your request to accept JSON. You do it like this:

First set the header parameters of your request...

```
httpsURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); //header params
httpsURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json"); //header params
```

Then just send the JSONObject directly to the server like this...

```
outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream());
outputStreamWriter.write(someJsonObject.toString());
```